# JS: Nesting promise chains or keep them at same scope?

Tags: javascript

Do these essentially do the same thing? I came across this while in a Promise example and the lecturer had returned the fetch but wouldn't example 1 be another viable way of doing this as well?

**1**

```
fetch('url1')
.then(data => data.json())
.then(() => {
    fetch('url2')
    .then((response) => {
       // do things
    })
})
```

**2**

```
fetch('url1')
.then(data => data.json())
.then(() => {
    return fetch('url2')
    
})
.then((response) => {
    // do the same thing but at same scope
});
```

Comment: Yes, it would be, but generally people prefer to avoid nesting as it causes an increasing amount of indentation the more chains you have, leading to the code being halfway across the screen.

Comment: They're not *exactly* identical, but pretty close. In general, there's no reason to do #1 instead of #2, and lots of reasons to do #2 instead. The only reason to do #1 is if you don't want the outer promise to actually wait for `url2` and that whole chain to finish

Answer (score 1):

In example 1, the second `then()` resolves to `undefined`

In example 2, the second `then()` adopts the promise returned by the second `fetch` and so the final `then` could return something usable at the top level return value.

---

Either way. It's quite verbose code that could be a lot clearer using `async` and `await`.